# Rust sqlx don't save anything to database

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-sqlx

After creating `Postgres<pool>` and execute query. Database doesn't include any changes,
but if I execute the same INSERT with the unique field, it returns an Error like it already exists.

```rust
let from_ssl = |ssl: bool| -> PgSslMode {
    match ssl {
        true => PgSslMode::Require,
        false => PgSslMode::Disable,
    }
};
let conn = PgConnectOptions::new()
    .host(db.host.as_str())
    .port(db.port)
    .username(db.user.as_str())
    .password(db.password.as_str())
    .ssl_mode(from_ssl(db.ssl));

let pool = PgPoolOptions::new()
    .max_connections(5)
    .idle_timeout(Some(Duration::new(60, 0)))
    .connect_with(conn)
    .await?;

Ok(DbBuilder { pool })
```

```rust
sqlx::query!("INSERT INTO configs \
            (name, is_available, membership_id, priority_index, params)\
            VALUES( $1, $2 ,$3 ,$4, $5);",
               name, is_available, 1, 1, params)
                .execute(&db.pool)
                .await?;
```

Comment: "Database doesn't include any changes" - how do you check this?

Comment: using the database console or directly viewing the information in it

Comment: Not an expert of sqlx, but from description you are not committing: the key is duplicated inside your transaction, so you get the error, but reading outside you see nothing, wich can be normal if not committed.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/3182456/user-0 thanks for your replay. However, it still doesn't work. 
Next code solved my problem, but i am still don't really understand what is a difference

` let pool = PgPoolOptions::new()
            .connect(db_url.as_str())
            .await?;`

Answer (score 0):

Next code solved my problem, but i  don't really understand what is a difference
`let pool = PgPoolOptions::new() .connect(db_url.as_str()) .await?;`